# Close button for typo3 modalbox

Tags: jquery, typo3-7.6.x

I have found a perfect instruction for a modalbox with TYPO3 (http://www.andreas-hoffmeyer.de/blog/content-als-lightbox.html). The opening is fine for all kind of content elements but the author didn't integrate a close button and asking him for a hint wasn't successful.

I have some Typoscript

```
modal = PAGE
modal {
  typeNum = 123
  config {
    no_cache = 1
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    disablePrefixComment = 1
  }  
  10 < styles.content.get
  10 {
    select {    
      andWhere.data = GP:cid
      andWhere.intval = 1     
      andWhere.if.isTrue.data = GP:cid
      andWhere.wrap = uid=|  
    }
  }
}
```

and some jquery

```
(function(window, document, $) {
    "use strict"
    $('.download').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // erstmal alle bisherigen Modalboxes entfernen
        $('.download').remove();
        var uri = [];       
        uri = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
        if (uri[1]) {   
            var cid = uri[1].replace(/[a-z]/gi, '');
            $.get(uri[0], {cid: cid, type: 123}, function(data, status) {
                appendToBody(data, status);
            });
            return true;
        }
        $.get(uri[0], {type: 123}, function(data, status) {
            appendToBody(data, status);
        });
    });
    function appendToBody(data, status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            throw Error('Error getting the content');
        }

        $('<div>', {
            id: 'modal',
            css: {
                (...)
            }
        }).html(data).appendTo('body');     
    }
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Now I need a close button inside the modalbox and it would be great to have the modalbox closed by clicking somewhere outside the modal box.

I tried it this way without success:

I created a new HTML Content Element in TYPO3 on the page that is shown in the modalbox and added

```
<p class="close">Close Window</p>

<script>
$( '.close' ).click(function() {
  $('.download').remove();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. This works fine for me:

```
<p class="close">Fenster schließen</p>

<script>
     (function(window, document, $) {
         $( '.close' ).click(function() {
              $('#modal').remove();
         });
    })(window, document, jQuery);
</script>
```